# Creating a custom control...Cannot create a 'text' property?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, custom-controls

## Solution

I did some googling and [found this forum post](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/component-development/26453-custom-control-public-overrides-property-text.html), and here is what I needed to do:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(True), Bindable(True), _
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return ControlText.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ControlText.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

---

I should state that I am really new to creating custom controls, so I do not know all of the ins-and-outs of the whole process.

I am creating a custom control that functions similarly to a checkbox, but uses two images as checked/unchecked. I am trying to add a Text property, but it gives me this warning:

```
Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return ControlText.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ControlText.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

> "property 'Text' shadows an overridable method in the base class 'UserControl'. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'."

Ok, so that is no problem. I change my declaration to `Overrides Property Text() As String`, but when I go to test it out 'text' is not listed under properties. Is there additional steps I need take to get my result?

### More details

My control consists of 2 (or 3, depending on how you look at it):

1. PictureBox - Displays a checked/unchecked image
2. Label - The Text that is being displayed on the control
3. PictureCheckBox - This is the actual control's name

The PictureBox is docked to the left of the PictureCheckBox, and the Label is docked on the right side:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Scratched the bit about Text being non-virtual.  It is in fact virtual / overridable.

But I'm curious, why do you want to do this.  In your specific example you're just calling into the base property so it doesn't appear to do anything.

Where are you expecting this value to be shown and how are you setting it?

<strike>Text is a non-virtual / overridable method on Control.  There is no way for you to override the property.  If you want to re-define the property you can use the Shadows keyword.</strike>

Comment: My control consists of a PictureBox and a Label. I suppose I'll just create a separate property that does the same function, just named differently. (shadows did not work either)

Comment: There are no errors, just the property does not show up. If I make the property "MyText" or anything else it will show up and function as I am intending.

Comment: @Anders, can you give us a little more context here.  Where do you expect it to show up?

Comment: @Anders, mainly can you give an example of how your are showing this value and how you set it?

Comment: @jared, does that image help?

Comment: @Anders a bit.  Where are you setting this value though?  Are you just grabbing the text from the selected label?

Comment: @jared, yes. it reads and writes from the label's text property

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure it's a public property

Answer (score 1):

> **Public Overridable** Property Text() As String
>
> ```
> Get
>     Return ControlText.Text
> End Get
> Set(ByVal value As String)
>     ControlText.Text = value
> End Set End Property
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a stupid question, but some of them still needs to be asked just to make sure:

Have you *compiled* since you made the changes? Using hotkeys in Visual Studio, press `[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[b]` to compile the entire solution.